# What counts as mutating state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Background is at the top, my actual question is simple enough, at the bottom, but I provided the context in case I'm going about this totally wrong and my question turns out to not even be relevant. I have only been using react for about two weeks.

What I'm trying to do is create a singleton, re-usable backdrop that can be closed either by clicking it, or by clicking a control on the elements that use a backdrop. This is to avoid rendering multiple backdrops in multiple places in the DOM (e.g. grouping a backdrop with each different type of modal, side drawer or content preview) or have multiple sources of truth for the state of the backdrop.

What I've done is create the Backdrop itself, which is not exported

```
const Backdrop = props => (
  props.show ? <div onClick={props.onClose} className={classes.Backdrop}></div> : null
);
```

I've also created a backdrop context, managed by a WithBackdrop higher order class component which manages the state of the backdrop and updates the context accordingly

```
class WithBackdrop extends Component {
  state = {
    show: true,
    closeListeners: []
  }

  show() {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  }

  hide() {
    this.state.closeListeners.map(f => f());
    this.setState({ show: false, closeListeners: [] });
  }

  registerCloseListener(cb) {
    // this.setState({ closeListeners: [...this.state.closeListeners, cb]});
    // Does this count as mutating state?
    this.state.closeListeners.push(cb);
  }

  render() {
    const contextData = {
      isShown: this.state.show,
      show: this.show.bind(this),
      hide: this.hide.bind(this),
      registerCloseListener: this.registerCloseListener.bind(this)
    };
    return (
      <BackdropContext.Provider value={contextData}>
        <Backdrop show={this.state.show} onClose={this.hide.bind(this)} />
        {this.props.children}
      </BackdropContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default WithBackdrop;
```

I've also exported a 'backdropable' HOC which wraps a component with the context consumer

```
export const backdropable = Component => (props) => (
  <BackdropContext.Consumer>
    {value => <Component {...props} backdropContext={value}/>}
  </BackdropContext.Consumer>
);
```

The usage of this API would be as follows: Wrap the part of your Layout/App that you want to potentially have a backdrop, and provide the context to any component that would activate a backdrop. 'Backdropable' is a just a lazy word I used for 'can trigger a backdrop' (not shown here, but I'm using TypeScript and that makes a little more sense as an interface name). Backdropable components can call show() or hide() and not have to worry about other components which may have triggered the backdrop, or about multiple sources of truth about the backdrop's state.

The last problem I had, however, was how to trigger a backdropable components close handler? I decided the WithBackdrop HOC would maintain a list of listeners so that components that need to react when the backdrop is closed by clicking the backdrop (rather than by that backdropable component's close button or something). Here is the modal component I'm using to test this

```
const modal = (props) => {
  props.backdropContext.registerCloseListener(props.onClose);

  return (
    <div
    className={[
      classes.Modal,
      (props.show ? '' : classes.hidden)
    ].join(' ')}>
    {props.children}
    <button onClick={() => {
      props.onClose();
      props.backdropContext.hide()
    }}>Cancel</button>
    <button onClick={props.onContinue}>Continue</button>
  </div>
  )
} 

export default backdropable(modal);
```

As far as I understand, it is best practice to never mutate state. My question is, does pushing to an array maintained in state count as mutating state, and what potentially bad consequences should I expect from this? Should I copy the array into a new array with the new element every single time, or will I only get undefined React behaviour if I try to change the reference of a state member. As far as I understand react only shallowly compares previous and next state to determine re-renders and provides utilities for more complicated comparisons, and so this should be fine right? The reason is that the array copying method triggers a re-render, then the modal tries to re-register the closeListener, then WithBackdrop tries to add it again...and I get an infinite state update loop.

Even if there is nothing wrong with simply pushing to the same array, do you think there is a better way to go about doing this?

Thanks, I sincerely appreciate the efforts anyone who tries to answer this long question.

**EDIT:** `this.setState({ closeListeners: [...this.state.closeListeners, cb]});` results in an infinite state-update loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mutating state in React is when you change any value or referenced object in state without using `setState`.

> As far as I understand, it is best practice to never mutate state. My
>   question is, does pushing to an array maintained in state count as
>   mutating state,

Yes

> and what potentially bad consequences should I expect from this?

You can expect to change the value of state and not see the ui update.

> Should I copy the array into a new array with the new element every
>   single time,

Yes:

```
const things = [...this.state.things]
// change things
this.setState({ things })
```

> or will I only get undefined React behaviour if I try to
>   change the reference of a state member. As far as I understand react
>   only shallowly compares previous and next state to determine
>   re-renders and provides utilities for more complicated comparisons,
>   and so this should be fine right?

It will compare if you call `setState` and update if necessary. If you do not use `setState`, it won't even check.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't want the UI to update here, I just want to add a function reference to the list. Oh wait, perhaps I should just maintain this list in the context object.

Comment: @AnthonyDeVellis Everything in `this.state` should effect the view in some way (`this.setState` triggers a render). If this is not the case you should not use `this.state` but create your own property. For example `this.closeListeners` could hold the array of listeners. You can modify this custom property however you like.

Answer (score 1):

Any changes directly to the state (without `setState()`) = mutating the state. In your case it is this line:

```
this.state.closeListeners.push(cb);
```

As @twharmon mentioned, you change the values in the memory but this does not trigger the `render()` of your component, but your component will eventually updated from the parent components leading to ugly and hard to debug side effects.
The solution for your problem using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax:

```
this.setState({
    closeListeners: [...this.state.closeListeners, cb]
});
```

PS: Destructuring also helps to keep your code cleaner:

```
const Backdrop = ({ show, onClose }) => (
  show ? <div onClick={onClose} className={classes.Backdrop}></div> : null
);
```